# PHP-FPM disallowing all connections

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, fastcgi

I have a separate apache container which should be using this php-fpm container. When I try to access localhost and use the website the error occours.

The error from my php fpm log:

```
[13-Sep-2019 15:37:12] WARNING: [pool www] child 21 said into stderr: "ERROR: Connection disallowed: IP address '172.23.0.5' has been dropped."
```

The important bits of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2.0.20190823.1-with-sources
WORKDIR /srv/www

RUN yum -y update

RUN amazon-linux-extras install -y php7.2 epel

COPY php.ini /etc/php.d/zz-docker.ini
# For some reason this doesn't work, so we use this file to append to configs later to get around the issue
COPY php-fpm.conf /etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["bash"]
```

The important bits of the entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# For some reason the php fpm config isn't being picked up in the .d directory so we append to the end of the configs
sudo bash -c "cat /etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf >> /etc/php-fpm.conf"
sudo bash -c "cat /etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf >> /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf"

sudo php-fpm --daemonize

bash -c "$@;"
```

The php-fpm.conf file:

```
[global]
daemonize = yes
error_log = /srv/www/var/log/php-fpm-error.log

[www]
listen = [::]:9001
chdir = /srv/www
catch_workers_output = Yes
```

I can't see any reason why the connection would be refused, it should be accepting any connection from port 9001.

The error from the apache container log:

```
[Fri Sep 13 15:37:12.560691 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 9:tid 140187870595816] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 172.23.0.6:41708] AH01074: Failed writing Environment to :
```

EDIT: Since the original post I've refined how php-fpm configs are added, now I'm appending the global setting changes to the php-fpm.conf file and the www settings to the php-fpm.d/www.conf file. This has highlighted to me that the added www pool settings seem to be ignored, but the added global settings are fine.

Comment: One of the first things I'd try is changing the Dockerfile to have `CMD ["php-fpm"]` (without the daemonize option), and replacing the last two lines of the entrypoint script with `exec "$@"`, then running the container without the `docker run -d` option.  (Run the main container process as a foreground process, and run the container in the foreground.)  Does it actually start up?

Comment: The container does other stuff to, these are cut down files to remove unnecessary reading and minimalise the example. Functionally changing where php-fpm gets executed in the entrypoint script won't change anything, it's running fine and I've even validated the config with `php-fpm -t` no issue. It's seemingly ignoring the listen option and I don't know why. 

This is all done through docker compose so I don't actually use docker run.

Comment: For some stupid reason it seems like new files in the .d/ directory don't work and also using the [global] tag straight up causes the stuff in the [www] to not work. So my solution was to only have the bit after [www] and just append to /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf. I'd love it if anyone has a proper solution or reason as to why it isn't working normally

Answer (score 0):

Just a copy of my comment I made two years ago when I fixed this:

For some reason it seems like new files in the .d/ directory don't work and also using the [global] tag straight up causes the stuff in the [www] to not work. So my solution was to only have the bit after [www] and just append to /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf. I'd love it if anyone has a proper solution or reason as to why it isn't working normally